# Is it possible to displace cerium from cerium sulphate using aluminium to get pure cerium metal?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm unable to find cerium any reactivity series, hence the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No

The std. electrode potential for Ce3+/Ce is -2.33V, the std. electrode potential for Al3+/Al is -1.66V. This shows that Al is not reactive enough to reduce Ce(III), it is reactive enough to take Ce(IV) to Ce(III) so I think you would get a mixed salt of Ce/Al sulfate.

This reference [here](http://www.chemistryexplained.com/elements/A-C/Cerium.html) states that calcium metal is used with cerium fluoride as a preparative method.

Note: you can't do this in aqueous solution. Your reactive metal will react with the water preferentially.

Comment: Is it possible to simply add a highly reactive metal like aluminium to a solution  of ceric sulphate? Forgive me is this question sounds silly but  I'm new to chemistry.

Comment: The electrode potentials show that Aluminium is not reactive enough to reduce Cerium. It requires metal with electrode potential below -2.33V.  Potassium,  Sodium and Lithium would  do it in addition to Ca. Ce has a reactivity close to Magnesium (-2.37V). Also note; you can't do this in aqueous solution. Your reactive metal will react with the water preferentially.

Comment: Not to mention that sulfates would get reduced to sulfides in the presence of such powerful reducing agents. That is wasteful of your reducing agent.

Comment: Thanks! May I know if it is possible to use electrolysis to extract cerium?

Comment: @mayur-sharmila yes it is. The reference I quoted in the answer mentions electrolysis of cerium chloride as a preparative method. If you are happy with the answer, please accept it.